# Graph API /threads messages usage limitations

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-recommendations, facebook-batch-request, facebook-messages

With regards of using the /threads object from Graph API I want to know if a public figure account has some limitation regarding the amount of received messages / day and to know if a Facebook application that reads them using /threads has limitation to access the entire list.

Suppose I develop an app used by a public figure that would receive 500k(or above) messages a day. Can I access all the messages (using a paging technique, of course)? Is there any chance to have the account removed or app disabled because of extensive usage of messages? If there is a need to pay for an account (and-or application) with such a usage, where do I find the pricing list?

Thank you.